# Boost thread join seg fault on pthread_join while accessing an offset from thread_data_base

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

```
Crash is seen when pthread code tries to access an offset from thread_handle
#0  0x00007f6c7459b7d8 in pthread_join () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007f6c7438c310 in boost::thread::join (this=0x4069ef0)

Here is the thread info from object (this=0x4069ef0):

$14 = (boost::detail::thread_data_base *) 0x3c2fd90
(gdb) p  *$9.px
$15 = {
  <boost::enable_shared_from_this<boost::detail::thread_data_base>> = {
    weak_this_ = {
      px = 0x3c2fd90,
      pn = {
        pi_ = 0x3c2ff20
      }
    }
  },
  members of boost::detail::thread_data_base:
  _vptr.thread_data_base = 0x102c3f0,
  self = {
    px = 0x0,
    pn = {
      pi_ = 0x0
    }
  },
  thread_handle = 140103459141968,
```

Accessing contents from thread_handle causing segfault. On trying to view contents from *thread_handle

> Cannot access memory at address 0x7f6c60e9f950

Boost version is boost-1.41.0

Here is the code which creates the thread

```
t1 = new boost::thread(boost::bind(&test::Th, this));
```

Later while cleanup

```
t1->join();
```

cause  seg fault

Comment: The problem is not in the code you have posted here.  Can you give us a minimal example program that we can compile to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I am seeing a similar problem under OSX using 1.55.  Did you get to the bottom of the issue?

Comment: We had some code which was intercepting pthreads and releasing the stack allocated by using pthread api. Later when boost was accessing the it as the stack was gone we were seeing issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had some code which was intercepting pthreads and releasing the stack allocated by using pthread api. Later when boost was accessing the it as the stack was gone we were seeing issue.